# How to call openDrawer on DrawerNavigator from child BottomTabBarNavigator TabItem click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to react and react native and I am trying to figure out react-native-navigation.

I want to have a TabBarNavigator nested in a DrawerNavigator and open the drawer when one of the tabBarItems is tapped

Everything works as intented (sliding right opens the drawer,  and tapping changes TabBar screen except the menu btn), but I can not delegate the action correctly I guess..

Any help appreciated!

Here is what I have so far

```js
const ActivitiesStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    MyActivities: {screen: MyActivities},
    ActivityDetail: {screen: ActivityDetail},
    ActivityLikes: {screen: ActivityLikes},
    ActivityComments: {screen: ActivityComments}
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'MyActivities'
  }
);

ActivitiesStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={
        Platform.OS === 'ios'
          ? `ios-paper`
          : 'md-paper'
      }
    />
  ),
};

const ConversationStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Messages: {screen: Conversations},
    Chat: {screen: Chat}
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Messages'
  });

ConversationStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
    <TabBarIconWithBadge
      badgeCount={3}
      focused={focused}
      name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? `ios-chatbubbles` : 'md-chatbubbles'}
    />
  ),
};

const GameStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Game: {screen: Game}
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Game'
  });

GameStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? `ios-square${focused ? '' : '-outline'}` : 'md-square'}
    />
  ),
};

const RequestsStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    MyRequests: {screen: MyRequests}
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'MyRequests'
  });


const UrgentRequestStack = createStackNavigator({
  UrgentRequest: {screen: UrgentRequest}
  
});

UrgentRequestStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? `ios-add-circle${focused ? '' : '-outline'}` : `md-add-circle${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`}
    />
  ),
};


const SettingsStack = createStackNavigator({
  Settings: {screen: SettingsScreen}
});

function onMenuPress() {
  return true;
}

const EmptyStack = createStackNavigator({
  Main: {
    screen: () => null,
  },
});

EmptyStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarIcon: ({focused, navigation}) => (
    <TabBarIcon //navigation={navigation}
      focused={focused}
      name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? `ios-menu` : `md-menu`}
    />
  ),
};


const MainTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  EmptyStack,
  ActivitiesStack,
  UrgentRequestStack,
  ConversationStack,
  GameStack
}, {
  tabBarOptions: {showLabel: false},
  initialRouteName: 'ActivitiesStack'
});

const defaultGetStateForAction = MainTabNavigator.router.getStateForAction;


MainTabNavigator.router.getStateForAction = (action, state) => {
  // console.log(action)
  if (action.routeName === 'EmptyStack') {
    
    // Returning null from getStateForAction means that the action
    // has been handled/blocked, but there is not a new state
    // action.navigation.openDrawer;
    
    return null;
    
  }
  return defaultGetStateForAction(action, state);
}


const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    RequestsStack,
    SettingsStack,
    ConversationStack,
    ActivitiesStack,
    MainTabNavigator
  },
  {
    contentComponent: CustomDrawerContent,
    drawerType: 'slide',
    initialRouteName: 'MainTabNavigator'
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator({
  // You could add another route here for authentication.
  // Read more at https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html
  Main: DrawerNavigator,
}));
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turns out is really simple when you read the api carefully...

Posting in case someone finds it useful:
Replace the `EmptyStack.navigationOptions` with the following

```js
EmptyStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarOnPress: ({ navigation }) => { navigation.openDrawer() },
  tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? `ios-menu` : `md-menu`}
    />
  ),
};
```

Comment: could u post a reference to the documentation where it says that please?